# How to recover the lost data in ubuntu 14.04.

Tags: data-recovery

I am not able to recover my files as I have accidentally deleted the files. Is there any application which will help me to recover the files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an app names "testdisk". You can directly start it from terminal by typind sudo testdisk or photorec. If it isn't installed then you can install it by "sudo apt-get install testdisk".